# How to get the correct answer for Linear Regression in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression, nan

I'm not getting output on linear regression problem.
It is simple one variable linear regression problem.
I have used Kaggle's Linear regression dataset,
from here : [Linear Regression on Random Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/tanveerbaba/linear-regression-on-random-dataset)

It is not giving the desired output.It is giving nan value of weights and bias

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# In[20]:


#Getting DataFrames
train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

#Dropping NaN rows
train_data.dropna()
test_data.dropna()

#Getting features and labels
X_train = train_data.iloc[:,0].values
Y_train = train_data.iloc[:,1].values

test_X = test_data.iloc[:,0].values
test_Y = test_data.iloc[:,1].values

#Plotting Training Data
plt.scatter(X_train,Y_train)


# In[58]:


#Training the model

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='Y')

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]),dtype=tf.float32,name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]),dtype=tf.float32,name='bias')

Y_pred = W*X + b

cost = tf.square(Y_pred,name='cost')

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# In[61]:


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={X:X_train,Y:Y_train})
    W_out,b_out = sess.run([W,b])
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/linear_reg', sess.graph)


print(W_out,b_out)


# In[60]:


#plt.plot(X_train, W_out*X_train + b_out, color='red')
plt.scatter(X_train,Y_train)
plt.plot(X_train, W_out*X_train + b_out, color='red')
```

And it is giving output:

```
nan nan
```

Weights and bias are getting nan values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned any weights and bias. You defined your weights as

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]),dtype=tf.float32,name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]),dtype=tf.float32,name='bias')
```

Here, input to `tf.random_normal` is an empty array. So, both `W` and `b` are empty. You'll need to specify the shape of `W` and `b`, which for `W` will be `[in_dim, out_dim]` and for `b` will be `[out_dim]`. Check the [`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal) documentation, here the first argument is the shape of the required tensor.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your cost function there is a small bug, it probably should be `cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y_pred - Y,name='cost'))`.

Second, layog has a point, the shapes of `W` and `b` should be provided when the parameters are defined. Anyways, since you are using `Y_pred = W*X + b`, thus avoiding `tf.matmul`, not explicitly providing shapes does work, using the new cost function.

Third, playing with your code I found that `GradientDescentOptimizer` does not seem to do well with the given learning rate and a few I tried manually, even though I really think it should, meh. `AdamOptimizer`, however, does fine.

The code below tweaks your example slightly and should work:

```
# casting data into rank-2 form for tensorflow
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,1))
test_X = test_X.reshape((-1,1))

Y_train = Y_train.reshape((-1,1))
test_Y = test_Y.reshape((-1,1))

tf.reset_default_graph()

D = X_train.shape[1] # number of non-bias features

#Training the model
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,D), name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1), name='Y')

# with explicit definition of shapes
# W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([D,1], mean=0., stddev=1.), dtype=tf.float32, name='weights')
# b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1], mean=0., stddev=1.), dtype=tf.float32, name='bias')

# without explicit definition of shapes
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([], mean=0., stddev=1.), dtype=tf.float32, name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([], mean=0., stddev=1.), dtype=tf.float32, name='bias')

#Y_pred = tf.matmul(X,W) + b # doesn't like undefined shapes
Y_pred = X*W + b # fine with undefined shapes
error = Y_pred - Y
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="cost")

# optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-1)
update = optimizer.minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

Niter = 500
Nprint = 50
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(Niter):
        sess.run(update, feed_dict={X:X_train, Y:Y_train})
        if i%Nprint == 0:
            print("\n%i/%i" % (i+1,Niter))
            print("W",W.eval())
            print("b",b.eval())
            print("cost",cost.eval(feed_dict={X:X_train, Y:Y_train}))

    W_out, b_out = sess.run([W, b])
```